# Slack User Presence Subscription with Botkit startRtm

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I am trying to figure out how to subscribe to presence changes in Slack via Botkit's startRTM call. Currently I'm using [Botkit's starter slack bot](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-slack) which has an rtm_manager script for handling all rtm starts and closes.

```
bot.startRTM(function(err, bot) {
   ...do stuff
});
```

I've looked into Slack's new way of subscribing to presence events, and understand that I need to send a *presence_sub* or *batch_presence_aware*  parameter in order to subscribe to the *presence_change* event.

I've also looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/master/docs/_pages/rtm_client.md#subscribing-to-presence-updates) for the node-slack-sdk rtm client for handling presence updates, which uses rtm.start itself

```
rtm.start({
   batch_presence_aware: true
});
```

Since I am using botkit, which uses a startRTM method, I am struggling to understand how to combine all of this information. ***Is there any documentation or examples for subscribing to presence updates while using botkit's startRTM method?***

Comment: Doesn't Botkit also support the Events API?

Comment: @MatejMecka It does, but Slack has changed how presence events work recently - from what I understand I need to subscribe by passing a parameter to the rtm.start method. When I go to api.slack.com/apps there is no option in the event subscriptions for presence.

Answer (score 0):

I think first we should separate the two concepts: `presence_sub` and `batch_presence_aware`.

1. `presence_sub` is an RTM message type which your app can send to Slack to indicate for which users your client would like presence updates regarding.
2. `batch_presence_aware` is a argument that your app can set when calling `rtm.start` if you'd like presence updates about different users to be grouped into a single message. Each update arrives as a `presence_change` event. The tradeoff is that your app might not get the `presence_change` as soon as possible, but it would be dealing with fewer messages which can benefit performance. This is optional but recommended.

The "new way" you are referring to is a change in behavior since January 2018. Previous to the change, your app *could have* supplied a `presence_sub` argument to `rtm.start`, which would opt your connection into receiving `presence_change` events for only the users that were indicated in the last `presence_sub` message; otherwise your app would receive those updates for every user in the workspace. Since the change, `presence_sub=true` for all connections, which effectively means your app **must** send a `presence_sub` message to get any `presence_change` events.

---

Now let's go through how you can use this information in Botkit.

1. Set up your controller to send messages over RTM.

   ```
   var controller = Botkit.slackbot({
     // ...
     send_via_rtm: true,
   });
   ```

   In the starter repo, the controller is created in `bot.js` and already contains a few options in `bot_options`. You'll need to ad the `send_via_rtm` option to allow for your sent messages to go over RTM. Unfortunately, Botkit doesn't have an API that will allow you to use `batch_presence_aware` that I'm aware of. If that's something you desire, I recommend opening an issue on the project.
2. Set up presence subscriptions for the users you want updates regarding.

   ```
   controller.say({
     type: "presence_sub",
     ids: [
       "U061F7AUR",
       "W123456"
     ]
   });
   ```

   You'll want to do this as early in your program as possible. In the starter repo, you might want to group this and the next step into a "skill", so placing it in a new file in that directory, inside the exported function would be a good option. Notice that you'll need a list of the user IDs for whom you want subscriptions. It's up to you how you'd like to source that list. **You also want to perform this same action, with a complete list of the users, each time you want to add or remove a subscription.**
3. Listen for presence change events

   ```
   controller.on('presence_change', (bot, event) => {
     // `event` contains presence information
     console.log(event);
   });
   ```

   Once a user for which you have set up a presence subscription changes presence status, you'll receive an event in this callback. The exact structure is described here: https://api.slack.com/events/presence_change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have tried implementing this, however I get a `controller.say is not a function` error when I try to run step 2 above. I also tried `bot.say` incase that's what you meant, which did not work either, with the error message `Cannot use the RTM API to send messages.` Could you clarify what method you are using there? I don't see "say" as a listed method in botkit's documentation.